# Detect whether it has post data on the current page with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http, post

Sometimes, if we post a form in `page A` (to `page B`), then we refresh the `page B`.

```
<!-- page A -->
<form action="page-b.html" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="data" />
</form
```

Then, when we try to refresh on `page B`, we was prompt to confirm whether submit the POST data again.

So, I'm trying to find a way to detect whether it has some post data (or http method to be post) on `page B`, something may looked like:

PS: jQuery is welcome

```
<!-- page B -->
<script>
    if(window.has_post_data()) {
        // do something in case
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Use AJAX, test to see if a var exists with a truthy condition.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to accomplish that using pure javascript or jquery. Javascript has no record of the HTTP method used to load the page. The best way to work around this issue would involve having the server add some specific variable or markup if the method was post, and search for that variable or markup using javascript.